# "object 'V1' not found" error after running a predict-command

Tags: r, dataframe, predict

Greatings all,

After using the `predict()` function for a LM model, I get

> object 'V1' not found

Do I need to prepare my 'z' data object on a different way?

```
Model <- readRDS('C:/model.rds')
x <- read.csv('C:/data.csv', header = FALSE)
y <- 0
for(i in 1:5){y[i] <- rank(data[1:100,i], na.last = TRUE, ties.method = 'last')[100] / 10}
z <- 0
z[1:6] <- c(y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], 0)
prediction <- predict(Model, data.frame(z))
```

Comment: Try `data.frame(V1 = z)`. If the model was fit with a variable name, `predict` expects that name as a column in `newdata`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rui. This leads to an "object 'V2' not found" error. In which format should I include all variables?

Comment: Put up to `V5` in the new data.frame.

Comment: Ah, so 'prediction <- predict(Model, data.frame(V1 = z, V2 = z, etc '. I wasn't aware of the exact format. I've got it working now, big thanks!